# How to make the π and 16 be on the same line?

Tags: ti-basic

So, I'm making a program on my TI-84 Plus that finds the area of a circle. I want it to display the approximate answer and the exact answer, but I can't get the latter to work. The code is this (I realize that it isn't very efficient):

```
Prompt R
ClrHome
(πR²)→A
(R²)→B
round(B,2)→B
Disp "A="
Disp ""
Disp "APPROXIMATION:"
Disp A
Disp "EXACT:"
Disp "π",B
Disp "PRESS ENTER"
Pause
```

However, it displays like this (when the radius is 4):

```
A=

APPROXIMATION:
               50.27
EXACT:
π
               16
PRESS ENTER
```

I would like to know how to make the π and 16 (in this case) be on the same line, with π before 16, and have it work for all number of digits. I've tried to use the Output( command, but if B is over 2 digits, it goes to the next line. Thanks!

Comment: Use `Output()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use Output(X,Y,"π") and Output(X,Y-3,B)
This is how I would do this:

```
    :Prompt R
    :ClrHome
    :(πR²)→A
    :(R²)→B
    :log(B)→C
    :round(B,2)→B
    :Output(1,1,"A")
    :Output(3,1,"APPROXIMATION:")
    :Output(3,16,A)
    :Output(5,1,"EXACT:")
    :Output(5,8,B)
    :Output(5,11+C,"π")
    :Output(7,1,"PRESS ENTER")
    :Pause
```

Basically, once the calculations are made, in this prgm text, the program would use log(B)→C to find how many spaces to move the π to the right. After that, it would output A at the first line of text, the approximation at the third line of the Home Screen grid (for Output), and the exact approximation, in terms of π, at the fifth line of the Home Screen grid (for Output).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this, but it kept giving me a domain error. I have yet to try to find a solution, but I think the `:Output(5,11+C` is the culprit. I looked around a bit, and saw that if you type `(1+int(log(abs(B)->C`, then it will accurately count the digits in the number, thus making it so that I can display it correctly. I still need to test it out, though, but it should work.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to round C. I'd add before the set of Output commands: round(C,0)->C

Comment: Even so, during my testing, I found that if the radius has a decimal, the decimal isn't counted in the `log(B)->C`; so what I ended up doing was changing the `EXACT:` to `R^2=`, then use the `disp` command to display B. Otherwise, the π would have been in the place in the decimal point, so things ended up looking like this (if the radius is 9.6, for example): `92π` then on the next line, `16`. Hence the change in format.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I tend to use `Output(` for displaying text, but there are another two ways you could do this.

1. You could use `Text(` (under the `Draw` menu) to write text to the graph screen. For this, you need to make sure that all graphs are off, axes are off, and grid is off (grid only applies for TI84 +C Silver Edition as far as I know).
2. You can use `Disp` to display a string containing the values you want. For this, you need to turn the value of `B` into a string. There are a few ways you can do this, one posted [here](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/number-to-string).